# How to show the correct/wrong sign in multiple choice (mcq) quiz

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, multiple-choice

Okay, Im creating a simple MCQ quiz in Flash. I want to make it like (more or less here is my concept), when I click on the answer, the correct/wrong sign will appears for few sec then redirected to the next question (which in the next frame/scene, but I would prefer frame).

As for now, my quiz runs with the correct/wrong sign appears on the next frame, then I need to create next button for the user to go to the next question.

Does anyone get what I am trying to say? Can you help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

so i guess you have an answer click handler function. And a sign `DisplayObject`.

so you just have to add this sign to stage on answer click, and then remove it after some time and go to next frame.

```
const delayMillis:uint = 1000;
var currentSign:DisplayObject;

function showNextFrame(event:TimerEvent):void {
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.COMPLETE, showNextFrame);
    if (currentSign && contains(currentSign)) {
        removeChild(currentSign);
    }

    mouseEnabled = true;
    museChildren = true;
    gotoAndStop(/* your frame num */);
}

function answerClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    currentSign = answerIsCorrect ? new CorrectSign() : new WrongSign();
    addChild(currentSign);

    // you want to prevent all the clicks, while the sign is on stage
    mouseEnabled = false;
    museChildren = false;

    const timer:Timer = new Timer(delayMillis, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.COMPLETE, showNextFrame);
    timer.start();
}
```

if I understood you right, this should help

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! GBU